# How can I get the raw JSON dictionary from ASP.NET MVC Web API post?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, json, web-services, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

With a ApiController subclass, it has the ability in Post method to bind it to an existing model object such as

```
public class RegisterController : ApiController
{
    public void Post(Product product)
```

but if the incoming JSON data contains data that I'll use to create multiple model objects, how can I get to the data directly?

```
    public void Post(dynamic value)
```

returns value as null. Is there an easy shorthand way of getting to it like request.POST['name'] or something?

Let's say the data looks like

```
{
    'productID':1,
    'productName':'hello',
    'manufacturerID':1,
    'manufacturerName':'world'
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One option may be using one of the ReadAsAsync* methods in HttpContent instance off of the Request object

```
public void Post() {
   var result = this.Request.Content.ReadAsAsync<string>().Result;
}
```

I don't know what format you're sending your data in, but you can retrieve it this way.

You could try this too for multiple objects...

```
public void Post(IEnumberable<Product> products) {

}
```

Comment: Ah, this is what I missed out. The key was to not put any parameters in Post() or it will try to bind and ReadAsAsync will return empty